# Fuzzy and shadowy text rendering on LED TV

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, hdtv

Just bought a Toshiba 24" LED TV, and hooked up to new Gigabyte Radeon 7550 HD to my Windows 7 Desktop via 9' HDMI.

I updated all drivers.  The recommended resolution is 1980×1200, but text is fuzzy, shadowy and almost unreadable in all programs.

I tried using VGA cable, and got a 4×3 picture with equally lousy resolution.  Am I missing some setup maneuver?  Or is either TV or Video Card defective?

Answer (score 1):

If its just the *`text is fuzzy`* problem you may try [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/tune.aspx) to get it right, if there are other problems also, then try *restarting* your machine and then the last option would be `re-installation` of your GPU and drivers both..

Also do remember to set the Screen Resolution to "*recommended*" level (written in brackets), not as suggested by GPU, because at last the resolution must be supported by the monitor itself.

Comment: Thanks, Asif.  Already been the clear-type route; restarted several times; reinstalled drivers!?  Both VC & Monitor say they support the 1980 resolution.  And I tried the 1600 resolution with no difference in text!!   ????

Comment: then it must be something wrong with the Card, what happens if you uninstall the drivers, removes the card and get back to default GPU settings?

Comment: Finally got a chance to do a detailed troubleshoot.  Tried every cable/connection available, shorter cables thru new GC, then direct thru MB ports - still bad text.  Hooked up old monitor, tried both new GC and MB ports, and all allowable cables.  All worked fine.  TV is the problem, and no 'drivers' available to install to correct, so returning the Toshiba TV.  Thanks for your help.